# How to make text is constant in edit text in android app?

Tags: android-edittext

I have one edit text in one activity,

I make the text inside it as number and saved that number in shererdPreference.. and make that activity is visible once at the begging of the app, and return to that activity from the setting we made.

How to make that text is visible to user ( fixed ) in edit text?

Answer (score 0):

If the user should not be able to modify the text, use setEnabled(false).

Comment: and where and how to use it?

Comment: In the Activity's onCreated method or in any other method call textView.setEnabled(false).

Comment: no, the user be able to modify the text , and for the edit text not text view

Comment: EditText is inherited from TextView so it has the same setEnabled method.

Comment: Right, if you don't want user to modify the edit text. Why don't you try and see if it works as you expect?

Comment: because it saved in SharedPreferences, i want to see that in setting again and enable the user if he want to modify his number